# Convert to N tier architecture

Tags: asp.net

I want to convert my architecure into N tier architecture.Please find below details.
----------------------- Sql--------------------------------
USE [Practice]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Brand]    Script Date: 03/02/2019 00:56:50 ******/

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Brand](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [BrandName] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [ProductId] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Brand] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

USE [Practice]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Product]    Script Date: 03/02/2019 00:57:30 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProductName] [varchar](20) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Product] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

USE [Practice]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[BrandProductAssociation]    Script Date: 03/02/2019 00:58:00 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BrandProductAssociation](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [BrandId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProductId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Price] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Ingrdient] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [UseFor] [varchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
USE [Practice]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Proc_SelecBrand]    Script Date: 03/02/2019 00:58:39 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO



CREATE Procedure [dbo].[Proc_SelecBrand]  
@ProductId int = null  
as  
begin  
select * from Brand where (productid =@ProductId or @ProductId is null)  
end
GO


----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
USE [Practice]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Proc_SelecProduct]    Script Date: 03/02/2019 00:59:54 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


create Procedure [dbo].[Proc_SelecProduct]
as
begin
select * from Product
end
GO


------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
USE [Practice]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Proc_InsertBrandProductDetails]    Script Date: 03/02/2019 01:00:31 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO



create Procedure [dbo].[Proc_InsertBrandProductDetails]
@BrandId int,
@ProductId int,
@price int,
@Ingri varchar(10),
@user varchar(10)
as
begin
Insert into BrandProductAssociation ([BrandId],[ProductId],[Price],[Ingrdient],[UseFor]) values (@BrandId,@ProductId,@price,@Ingri,@user)
end
GO
```

---

```
------aspx----------------------------------------------------------------

<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestApp._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>

            <table style="width: 300px" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="4">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <asp:Label ID="LblMessage" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="height: 20px">
                    <td style="width: 100; background-color: #e5e5e5">
                        Product
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 200; background-color: #f7f7f7">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProduct" runat="server" Height="19px" Width="200px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlProduct_SelectedIndexChanged"
                            AutoPostBack="true">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <span style="color: Red">*</span>
                        <br />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFDProduct" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Select Product"
                            InitialValue="--Select Product--" ControlToValidate="ddlProduct" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="height: 20px">
                    <td style="width: 100; background-color: #e5e5e5">
                        Brand
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 200; background-color: #f7f7f7">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBrand" runat="server" Height="19px" Width="200px">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <span style="color: Red">*</span>
                        <br />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFDBrand" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Select Brand"
                            InitialValue="--Select Brand--" ControlToValidate="ddlBrand" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>

        <tr style="height: 10px">
            <td style="width: 100; background-color: #e5e5e5">
                Price
            </td>
            <td style="width: 200; background-color: #f7f7f7">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPrice" runat="server" Width="200px" Height="19px"></asp:TextBox><span style="color: Red">*</span>
                <br />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFDtxtPrice" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Price" Display="Dynamic"
                    ControlToValidate="txtPrice" ForeColor="Red" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="height: 10px">
            <td style="width: 100; background-color: #e5e5e5">
                Ingredient
            </td>
            <td style="width: 200; background-color: #f7f7f7">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtIngredient" runat="server" Width="200px" Height="19px"></asp:TextBox><span
                    style="color: Red">*</span>
                <br />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFDIngredient" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Ingredient"
                    ControlToValidate="txtIngredient" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="height: 10px">
            <td style="width: 100; background-color: #e5e5e5">
                Use
            </td>
            <td style="width: 200; background-color: #f7f7f7">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtUse" runat="server" Width="200px" Height="19px"></asp:TextBox><span style="color: Red">*</span>
                <br />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFDUse" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Use"
                    ControlToValidate="txtUse" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="height: 10px">
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <asp:Button ID="BtnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="BtnSubmit_Click" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>


</asp:Content>

----------------------------------------------------------------------                            _--------------- cs ------------------------------------------------------using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace TestApp
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["UserId"] = 2;

            if (Session["UserId"] == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
            }
            else
            { 
                if(!IsPostBack)
                {
                    PopulateBrand();
                    PopulateProduct();
                }
            }
        }

        private void PopulateProduct() 
        {
            try
            {


                DataSet ds = SqlHelpper.GetDataSet(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "Proc_SelecProduct", "Product", "PracticeConnectionString", null);

                if (ds != null)
                {
                    DataTable dt = ds.Tables["Product"];

                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        ddlProduct.Items.Insert(0, "--Select Product--");

                        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            ListItem lt = new ListItem(dr["ProductName"].ToString(), dr["Id"].ToString());

                            ddlProduct.Items.Add(lt);

                        }
                    }


                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        private void PopulateBrand()
        {
            try
            {
                string Product = null;

                if (ddlProduct.SelectedIndex > 0)
                {
                    Product = ddlProduct.SelectedItem.Value;

                }
                DataSet ds = SqlHelpper.GetDataSet(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "Proc_SelecBrand", "Product", "PracticeConnectionString",
                             new SqlParameter("@ProductId", Product));          


                if (ds != null)
                {
                    ddlBrand.DataSource = ds;
                    ddlBrand.DataTextField = "BrandName";
                    ddlBrand.DataValueField = "Id";
                    ddlBrand.DataBind();
                    ddlBrand.Items.Insert(0, "--Select Brand--");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }


        }

        protected void ddlProduct_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                PopulateBrand();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { 

            }
        }

        protected void BtnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int count = SqlHelpper.ExecuteNonQuery(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "Proc_InsertBrandProductDetails", "PracticeConnectionString",
                new SqlParameter("@BrandId",ddlBrand.SelectedItem.Value),
                new SqlParameter("@price",txtPrice.Text),
                new SqlParameter("@ProductId",ddlProduct.SelectedItem.Value),
                new SqlParameter("@Ingri",txtIngredient.Text),
                new SqlParameter("@user",txtUse.Text));

            if (count > 0)
            {
              // Show message

                //clean control 

                txtIngredient.Text = "";
                txtPrice.Text = "";
                txtUse.Text = "";
                ddlBrand.SelectedIndex = 0;
                ddlProduct.SelectedIndex = 0;
                LblMessage.Text = "BrandProduct details inserted sucessfully.";


            }
        }
    }
}
```

-------------------- Helper class created under app_code-------------------------------------

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace TestApp
{
    public class SqlHelpper
    {
        public static DataSet GetDataSet(CommandType cmdType, string cmdText, string tabName, string connString, params SqlParameter[] cmdParms)
        {
            string Constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connString].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Constring);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn);
            cmd.CommandType = cmdType;

            if (cmdParms != null)
            {
               foreach(SqlParameter param in cmdParms)
               {

                   cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
               }
            }

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            try
            {
                da.Fill(ds, tabName);

                return ds;
            }
            catch
            {
                conn.Close();

                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }

        public static int ExecuteNonQuery(CommandType cmdType, string cmdText,string connString,params SqlParameter[] cmdParms)
        {
            SqlConnection conn=null;
            int val=0;
            try
            {
                string Constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connString].ConnectionString;

                conn = new SqlConnection(Constring);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                PrepareCommand(cmd, conn, null, cmdType, cmdText, cmdParms);
                val = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                // cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                int cat = val;
               conn.Close();
                return val;

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                conn.Close();
                throw;
                //trans.Rollback();
            }
            finally
            {
              conn.Close();
            }
    }

        private static void PrepareCommand(SqlCommand cmd, SqlConnection conn, SqlTransaction trans, CommandType cmdType, string cmdText, SqlParameter[] cmdParms)
        {
            if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                conn.Open();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = cmdText;
            if (trans != null)
                cmd.Transaction = trans;

            cmd.CommandType = cmdType;

            if (cmdParms != null)
            {
                foreach (SqlParameter parm in cmdParms)
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(parm);
            }
        }

     }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, your question is not clear and not specific please take a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There's no question here. What problem are you having? Without an actual question, this post is off topic for Stack Overflow. You might try the code review stack exchange site instead.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question is not really n-tier, because the you still have to build SQL commands or list stored procedure names in the ASP.Net code-behind.

If you want n-tier, you must make the `SqlHelper` methods shown here **private**. Then, for each query you need to run, add a new method for that specific query, using your current `GetDataSet()` and `ExecuteNonQuery()` methods to run the code. Additionally, this class should be in it's own class library project, to end up in it's own dll file.

Later, as the project grows, you can move the individual query methods to separate classes to create logical groupings and enforce different kinds of security, and make the methods in your `SqlHelper` **internal** instead of private to facilitate that change.